# EXTJS - How to invalidate a field

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I know about the method [markInvalid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-markInvalid), but as the doc states:

> this method does not cause the Field's validate or isValid methods to
>   return false if the value does pass validation. So simply marking a
>   Field as invalid will not prevent submission of forms submitted with
>   the Ext.form.action.Submit.clientValidation option set.

So my question is how to invalidate a field so that the isValid method will return false ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the value passes all field validators, there's no way. One option would be to create your own validator that would allow "invalidating".